# How to insert data into another table from dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `office1`  and `Office2`

I want to insert the chosen from dropdown list into

table `saveoffice`

drop.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="rtl"
lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>dependent dropdown list using jquery Ajax?</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/bootstrap-3.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="savedata.php" name="myForm" method="POST"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Select office 1 and get bellow Related office 2</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">offices 1:</label>
                <select name="office1" id="office2" class="form-control">
                <option value="">--- choose office 1 ---</option>

                    <?php
                        require('config.php');
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM office1";
                        $result = $con->query($sql);
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['off1']."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">offices 2</label>
                        <select name="office2" id="office2" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                        </select>

                        </div>
                      </br>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert Data" class="btn btn-danger">
            </div>

      </div>

    </div>

</div>


<script>
$( "select[name='office1']" ).change(function () {
    var stateID = $(this).val();
    if(stateID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxpro.php",
            dataType: 'Json',
            type:'POST',
            data: {'id':stateID},
            success: function(data) {
                $('select[name="office2"]').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('select[name="office2"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('select[name="office2"]').empty();
    }
});

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

ajaxpro.php

```
  <?php


   require('config.php');
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM office2
         WHERE off2_id LIKE '%".$_POST['id']."%'";
   $result = $con->query($sql);


   $json = [];
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json[$row['id']] = $row['off2'];
   }
   echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

savedata.php < it does not work

```
   <?php
include('config.php')

$off1 = $_POST['$offices1'];
$off2 = $_POST['$offices2'];
$query = " INSERT INTO `saveoffice`(`id`, `offices1`, `offices2`) VALUES (0,".$office1.",".$offices2.") ";

    $query_execute=mysqli_query($con,$query);
          if($query_execute)
                    {
                          header("location:drop.php?q=success");
                    }

          else
                    {
                            echo mysqli_error($con);
                            header("location:drop.php?e=error");
                    }

?>
```

May I request what changes I need to make to `savedata.php`
to insert data into the table `saveoffices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your form element names are `offices1` and `offices2`, but you're using `$offices1`, `$offices2` as your `$_POST` array keys. They should be `offices1`, `offices2`.

2) you assign your `$_POST` values to `$off1`, `$off2`, then build the query with `$offices1`, `$offices2`.

Follow all your variable names through the code and ensure they correspond. I think you're having some confusion between the array keys and the variable names. They are separate things. The `$_POST` array keys should match the `name=` elements in the form.

**Also, and this is VERY important**, you need to be sanitizing your input to the database. You're leaving yourself open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

You need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on all user supplied variables. Additionally, you might consider validating the input further. Say, for example, you're expecting a number between 1 and 100. Check that you've received a number between 1 and 100, display an error otherwise.

Furthermore, there are a few other things to consider such as protecting against [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Here is another post that goes into detail on the subject.

[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating variables named `$off1` and `$off2` but you're using other variables in your SQL statement named `$offices1` and `$offices2`:

```
$off1 = $_POST['$offices1'];
$off2 = $_POST['$offices2'];
$query = " INSERT INTO `saveoffice`(`id`, `offices1`, `offices2`) VALUES (0,".$office1.",".$offices2.") ";
```

Try changing `$offices1` to `$off1` and `$offices2` to `$off2`.